# How to screenshot a large SSIS Control Flow

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ssis, screenshot

Can someone help me find a tool or extension in VS2013 to get a screenshot of my SSIS control flow?

My flow has many sequence containers and everything is not fitting in my 17 inch monitor.

Is there a tool out there that can help me achieve this?

Comment: a screenshot tool? I use Lightshot, it's free and fantastic. Does the zoom capability help? I don't really understand what you're after. It does ring warning bells if your package is so complicated it can't fit on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I use this simple screen share tool called [Gyazo](https://gyazo.com/) for this all the time.
It's easy to use, make, and share screenshots as well as make gifs for times you need to scroll as in your case.

You can also easily edit the screenshots and write things or make arrows like this before you send them:
[image]